# LoginPath does not redirect (asp.net core)

Tags: c#, authentication, redirect, asp.net-core

On startup.cs on Configure I have:

```
app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions
{
    AuthenticationScheme = "Cookies",
    LoginPath = new PathString("/Account/Login/"),
    AccessDeniedPath = new PathString("/Account/Forbidden/"),
    AutomaticAuthenticate = true,
    AutomaticChallenge = true
});
```

On normal controller:

```
[Authorize]
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    public IActionResult Index() { return View();  }
}
```

On AccountController:

```
public class AccountController : Controller
{
    [AllowAnonymous]
    public IActionResult Login() { return View(); }
}
```

Accessing Home/Index, unauthenticated, should redirect to login, but returns blank page.
I receive 401 on fiddler, but pages does not redirect.
It seems like nothing`s wrong, but still does not work.
Does anyone know why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are experiencing issue with AutomaticChallenge option. This option is causing a conflict between IISIntegration and Cookie middleware, see detailed notes [here](https://github.com/aspnet/Announcements/issues/210).

If you are using [Authorize], the solution would be to add the following code to your startup.cs inside `ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)`

```
services.AddAuthorization(options =>
{
    options.DefaultPolicy = new AuthorizationPolicyBuilder("Cookies").RequireAuthenticatedUser().Build();
});
```

Comment: Thanks, Ross! Useful details!